# Can I show all categories and tag of each post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm currently creating a shortcode for a post list in WordPress. And here's my code

```
function mgc_post_default() { 


global $post;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'cat'     => '',
    'num'     => '5',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
), $atts));

$args = array(
    'cat'            => $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'order'          => $order,
    'orderby'        => $orderby,
);

$output = '';

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    
    setup_postdata($post);
    
    $output .= '<div class="movie-poster">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
    $output .= '<div><h2><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h2></div>';
    $output .= '<div>' . get_the_date() . '</div>';
    $output .= '<div>' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
    $output .= '<div>' . get_field( "status" ) . '</div>';
    $output .= '<div>' . get_the_category( $id )[0]->name . '</div>';
    $output .= '<div>' . get_the_tags( $id ) [1]->name . '</div>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div>'. $output .'</div>';
}

// Register shortcode

add_shortcode('mgc_post', 'mgc_post_default');
```

It's working, but the category and tag of each post just appeared 1. What I want is it can show all categories and tags info of each post.

So my question is how to show all those categories and tags for each post?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all categories for a post, use [wp_get_post_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/) instead of get_the_category. Then you just loop over the categories inside your foreach.

Same for the terms. But then use [wp_get_post_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/).

So something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post) {
    
    setup_postdata($post);

    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post );

    $foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
      
        $output .= '<div>' . $category->name . '</div>';
 
    } 
     
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @anotheraccount for the answer, but I've solved my own problem by adding this code '`get_the_tag_list()`' and '`get_the_category_list()`' to the `$output`